# Multiple sequential Tensorflow operations in same Session.run() call

Tags: tensorflow

As the title suggests, I want to run multiple Tensorflow operations in the same `Session.run()` call. Specifically, to make the problem more concrete, suppose I want to run multiple training iterations in a single call.

The standard way of doing that with multiple `Session.run()` calls would be something like this:

```
# Declare the function that we want to minimize
func = ...

# Create the optimizer which will perform a single optimization iteration
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(func)

# Run N optimization iterations
N = 10
with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )
    for i in range(N):
        sess.run( optimizer )
```

However, this of course will have some overhead because we are making multiple session calls. I assume that we could remove some significant overhead by somehow grouping the operations. I assume that either the `group` or `count_up_to` are what I should be using, but I cannot find any examples demonstrating how to use them for this case. Could somebody please point me in the right direction?

The ultimate goal is to define some compound operation that would run `N` iterations in a single call, so that the above could be transformed to something like this:

```
# Declare the function that we want to minimize
func = ...

# Create the optimizer which will perform a single optimization iteration
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(func)

# Create the compound operation that will run the optimizer 10 times
optimizeNIterations = ?????
with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )
    sess.run( optimizeNIterations )
```

EDIT::

As `musically_ut` points out, I could indeed chain the opertions together by forcing the problem to have feed dictionaries. But that feels like a solution to one very specific problem. My overall concern is how to sequentially execute operations in a single session run. I can given another example why you would want this....

Suppose now that in addition to wanting to run my optimizer, I want to retrieve the optimized values, let's say these lay in the variable `X`. If I want to optimize AND get the optimized values, I could try to do something like this

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )
    o, x = sess.run( [ optimizer, X ] )
```

But in fact this will not work because the operations (optimizer,X) do not run sequentially. I fundamentally need to have 2 session calls:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )
    o = sess.run( optimizer )
    x = sess.run( X )
```

The question is how one can combine these two calls into one.

Comment: As you are not using `feed_dict`, I assume that you are feeding in the input using queues? In that case, perhaps `sess.run([ optimizer ] * N)` would be just as efficient. However, I am not sure whether the overhead is significant enough to optimize for, do you have any numbers on hand?

Comment: I have both scenarios (with and without feed dicts). My understanding though was that the thing you propose is not guaranteed to run sequentially...

Comment: I just checked. The thing you propose does NOT execute the same command multiple times. The result is equivalent to `sess.run(optimizer)`

Comment: I DO understand what you are saying though... I could chain the operations together using feed dicts. But there is another issue that pops up, that I would like to see addressed (see edit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you could put whichever operations you'd like to run multiple times in a [tf.while_loop](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop). If the operations are independent, you may have to either set `parallel_iterations` to `1` or (better) use control dependencies to sequence the optimizer calls. For example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default():
  opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1)
  # Use a resource variable for a true "read op"
  var = tf.get_variable(name="var", shape=[], use_resource=True)
  def _cond(i, _):
    return tf.less(i, 20)  # 20 iterations
  def _body(i, sequencer):
    with tf.control_dependencies([sequencer]):
      loss = .5 * (var - 10.) ** 2
      print_op = tf.Print(loss, ["Evaluating loss", i, loss])
    with tf.control_dependencies([print_op]):
      train_op = opt.minimize(loss)
    with tf.control_dependencies([train_op]):
      next_sequencer = tf.ones([])
    return i + 1, next_sequencer
  initial_value = var.read_value()
  with tf.control_dependencies([initial_value]):
    _, sequencer = tf.while_loop(cond=_cond, body=_body, loop_vars=[0, 1.])
  with tf.control_dependencies([sequencer]):
    final_value = var.read_value()
  init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
  with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run([init_op])
    print(session.run([initial_value, final_value]))
```

Prints:

```
2017-12-21 11:40:35.920035: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [Evaluating loss][0][46.3987083]
2017-12-21 11:40:35.920317: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [Evaluating loss][1][45.4404]
2017-12-21 11:40:35.920534: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [Evaluating loss][2][44.4923515]
2017-12-21 11:40:35.920715: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [Evaluating loss][3][43.55476]
2017-12-21 11:40:35.920905: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [Evaluating loss][4][42.6277695]
2017-12-21 11:40:35.921084: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [Evaluating loss][5][41.711544]
2017-12-21 11:40:35.921273: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [Evaluating loss][6][40.8062363]
2017-12-21 11:40:35.921426: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [Evaluating loss][7][39.9120026]
2017-12-21 11:40:35.921578: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [Evaluating loss][8][39.028965]
2017-12-21 11:40:35.921732: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [Evaluating loss][9][38.1572723]
2017-12-21 11:40:35.921888: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [Evaluating loss][10][37.2970314]
2017-12-21 11:40:35.922053: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [Evaluating loss][11][36.4483566]
2017-12-21 11:40:35.922187: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [Evaluating loss][12][35.6113625]
2017-12-21 11:40:35.922327: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [Evaluating loss][13][34.7861366]
2017-12-21 11:40:35.922472: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [Evaluating loss][14][33.9727631]
2017-12-21 11:40:35.922613: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [Evaluating loss][15][33.1713257]
2017-12-21 11:40:35.922777: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [Evaluating loss][16][32.3818779]
2017-12-21 11:40:35.922942: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [Evaluating loss][17][31.6044941]
2017-12-21 11:40:35.923115: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [Evaluating loss][18][30.8392067]
2017-12-21 11:40:35.923253: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [Evaluating loss][19][30.0860634]
[0.36685812, 2.3390481]
```